# How should I solve the "Unable to locate package translate-shell"

Tags: debian

I'm trying to install `translate-shell` on Debian. I used `apt update && apt install translate-shell` and this is what I got:

[image]

Command line text:

```
root@panel:/# apt update && apt upgrade && apt install translate-shell
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
Fetched 92.4 kB in 1s (102 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package translate-shell
```

As you can see in the image, my OS is:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

The [repository](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell/wiki/Distros#debian--ubuntu) has **Debian** in its list.

I could do the same thing on Ubuntu and it got installed.

What should I do?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting

Comment: Your look goes to https://packages.debian.org/buster-backports/translate-shell which says it's in `contrib`. Have you enabled `contrib`?

Comment: @muru, that solved it. I added `contrib` from [here](https://gist.github.com/ChristopherA/680b4eeeeb6e9e4c7fc59c010a23b6cd) and it worked. Can you please send it as an answer to be accepted, it might help others in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Until I added **contrib** in my Devuan **sources.list** I couldn't find *translate-shell*:

## Package repositories

deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-updates main  contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-proposed-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-backports main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

## Source repositories

#deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus main non-free-firmware
#deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-updates main non-free-firmware
#deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-security main non-free-firmware
#deb-src http://deb.devuan.org/merged daedalus-backports main non-free-firmware